# Why dont working custom arrows and how render number current slide?

Tags: reactjs

The problem is that custom arrow buttons do not work, does not respond to clicks. And the second problem is I cannot display the number of the current slider.

Additionally, how you can display 2 sliders on the page. The first slider always has 70% width of the second 30%

*Below is an example of my code from the React page*

```
export const News = ({ pageContext }) => {

const sliderElements = [
    ...data.allStrapiArticle.nodes,
    ...data.allStrapiArticle.nodes,
    ...data.allStrapiArticle.nodes
];

function PrevArrow(props) {
    const { className, onClick } = props;

    return (
        <button className={className + ' outline-none'} onClick={onClick}>
            <IconArrowRight
            // className={className}
            // onClick={onClick}
            />
        </button>
    );
};

function NextArrow(props) {
    const { className, onClick } = props;

    return (
        <button className={className + ' outline-none'} onClick={onClick}>
            <IconArrowLeft
            // className={className}
            // onClick={onClick}
            />
        </button>
    );
};

const settings = {
    infinite: true,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    // autoplay: true,
    speed: 400,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <PrevArrow />,
    // beforeChange: (current, next) => this.setState({ activeSlide: next }),
    // afterChange: current => this.setState({ activeSlide2: current }),
    beforeChange: (current, next) => {
        console.log(current, next);
    },
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            },
        },
    ],
};


<Slider {...settings}>
    {sliderElements.map((article) => (
      <span>
        { + 1 }
      </span>
      {" / "}
      <span>
       {sliderElements.length}
      </span>
      <PrevArrow/>
      <NextArrow />
    ))};
```

Comment: remove comments then it will work

Comment: No,  "is not defined"